# Qt: Failure on accessing printers

Tags: c++, qt, printing, rpc

Some of my customers do not get any available printers in my Qt application. The log shows the following error message from Qt:

```
QWin32PrintEngine::initialize: OpenPrinter failed (The RPC service is not available)
```

It seems that the problem does not always occur, but quite often.

Does anybody have any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: What version of windows are you using?

Comment: At the time it happens, does printing work in other applications? It seems like the print spooler service is not running.

Comment: The two customers are using Windows 7, and they say that the printers work in other applications. One customer reported that the problem is fixed when starting my application with administrator rights (which sounds weird to me).